# Joe Biden says the world is back as global climate leader

Tags: phrase-meaning

Why not "the **U.S.** is back as global climate leader"?  "The world" is itself global, yet the U.S. is a country used to be the world leader.

Is "the world" used correctly here? Should it be "the U.S."?

> Will the World Trust Joe Biden to Lead on Climate?
> **Joe Biden says the world is back as global climate leader**, but restoring the U.S. as a central player is easier said than done

> Source: *Time*

[image]

Comment: Do you have a link?

Comment: https://time.com/5915120/biden-climate-change-world/ But it only appears in the meta data for the page.  Looks like a simple error by a tired journalist.

Comment: It is on the home page of the Time:  https://time.com/         The OP was picked up from its most noticeable headline right now. I've taken a screenshot but this forum doesn't offer the option of uploading images.

Comment: @NewPlanet - in Windows, you can use the Snipping Tool and then choose 'Edit', 'Copy', and then use the paste image link on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously a mistake. How can the 'world' be a 'global' leader? 'Global' means the whole world, and the world can't lead the world.

This headline shows Biden is talking about the US leading the world on climate change:

> Joe Biden Says the U.S. Will Lead on Climate.

Comment: I'm not so sure. The blurb still doesn't make sense to me when "U.S." replaces "world" because of "but restoring the U.S. as a central player is easier said than done." If the U.S. is back as global climate leader, why is it difficult to restore the U.S. as a central player? These ideas clash. I think there was some deeper confusion in the mind of the author than a simple mistaken word.

Comment: @TypeIA "these ideas clash"... I take it you're just discovering the world of politics.

Comment: Not exactly. Funny though. ;) My comment was based on linguistic semantics rather than politics.

Comment: I think it makes sense: he says it's back, but saying it's back doesn't necessarily make it so, since it's easier said than done. It is just about possible to construct an alternative interpretation, whereby Biden is saying that the world is back, meaning that world affairs and the future of the planet are once more a concern of the US. But I think that's probably more of a stretch.